# Handling more than three indices/super indices, tensorial calculus

Tags: matrices, tensors

I need to code an equation such as the following one :

$$ \frac{\partial u^j}{\partial q^i} = \frac{\partial \mathrm A^j_{pl}}{\partial q^i}\dot q^p \dot q^l + \frac{\partial \mathrm B^{jl}}{\partial q^i} \frac{\partial \mathrm X}{\partial q^l} $$

Where $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf q$ are $n\times 1$ size vectors, $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ are $n\times n$ size matrices and $\mathrm X$ is just a $1\times 1$ variable.

Now, I don't really feel at ease when it comes to handling more than three indices/superindices but I do understand that I have to obtain a vector of the same dimensions as the $\mathbf u$ vector in the equation...

So I guess I'll have to sum over the $i$ index, or the $j$ super index. Can anybody tell me which proposition is likely to be the right one?

**First proposition**

$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial q^i} = \frac{\partial \mathrm A^j_{pl}}{\partial q^i}\dot q^p \dot q^l + \frac{\partial \mathrm B^{jl}}{\partial q^i} \frac{\partial \mathrm X}{\partial q^l}\right) $$

**Second proposition**

$$ \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\left(\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial q^i} = \frac{\partial \mathrm A^j_{pl}}{\partial q^i}\dot q^p \dot q^l + \frac{\partial \mathrm B^{jl}}{\partial q^i} \frac{\partial \mathrm X}{\partial q^l}\right) $$

Comment: Just chasing indices, you should have a free $i$ and $j$ in each term, so the middle term ought to sum over $p=l$.  The last term already sums over $l$ if you are using the summation convention.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, that is correct, the summation convention is being used. And I do have a free i and j in each term which bothers me...

Comment: @RossMillikan Ok, thanks for your comment, I just understood what is going on exactly : in fact it is not a $n\times 1$ vector that I must obtain but a $n\times n$ matrix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, I was chasing the wrong thing all along. In fact, the equation

$$ \frac{\partial u^j}{\partial q^i} = \frac{\partial \mathrm A^j_{pl}}{\partial q^i}\dot q^p \dot q^l + \frac{\partial \mathrm B^{jl}}{\partial q^i} \frac{\partial \mathrm X}{\partial q^l} $$

is to be interpreted as a $n\times n$ sized matrix over the $i$ and $j$ indices...

Comment: I don't think you want to sum over $i,j$.  Your equation is supposed to result in an $n \times n$ matrix.  When you sum, you make it into a scalar equation (which is correct) that loses all the information of the individual entries.

Comment: @RossMillikan You're right, just edited my answer.